# Embedded database on Java

Tags: java, database

I need a database without having to run a server. It is not going to be big, 10MB and 5 columns at the most. I don't need it to have something like primary or foreign keys, just somewhere where I can write/read/edit.

But I don't know anything about embedded databases on Java, so what's the most used embedded database with persistent storage? So I can look tutorials up, because I couldn't find any good tutorial about it

Comment: http://sayrohan.blogspot.in/2012/12/choosing-light-weight-java-database.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## H2

[H2 Database](http://www.H2Database.com/) is a relational database engine built in pure Java. Actively developed by someone with a long history of making such products. Open-source and free-of-cost.

Can be used either embedded in your Java app, or run separately as a database server.

H2 could certainly handle your data and much more.

By default, H2 stores your data to disk in persistent fashion, with [ACID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant transactions to protect against corruption during a crash. Optionally, you can configure to run as an [In-Memory database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database)  but then your data disappears after a crash or shutdown.

You will need to learn about [relational databases](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) in general, about H2 specifically, and about how to communicate to a database from Java via [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC) with [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

By the way, you should *always* have a [primary key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key), even with a single table. If your data does not already contain a unique identifier, assign either a sequential number or a [UUID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) value to each row upon INSERT.

## Apache Derby

Another embedded relational database engine is [Apache Derby](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby), formerly IBM Cloudscape. Also distributed by Sun/Oracle as [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html). Written in pure Java.

Comment: Will it work if I build the jar file? I need the app to be "portable", I mean, if have the app, with an H2 embedded database, with data on it on my computer and I copy-paste it into a USB drive, then run it on another computer, will it have the same data?                                                                                                                                                                                        I don't know if used the prepositions right, "on my computer" and "into a USB drive", I'll be glad if you correct me. Thanks

Comment: @EstebanBal Yes.Try it, see for yourself..